# What does the こと mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

同じことをする対象は動作

What does koto in this sentence mean?

Comment: Could you provide more context please, this single sentence is not enough to tell you what the こと refers to. A source text or the surrounding paragraph would be helpful.

Comment: this is an instruction I stumbled upon on Matome N3 vocab book. And there is no other sentence prior to that.

Comment: Please be more specific, a page number would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It basically means *thing*. 同じ is a noun that can act prenominally, which means it doesn't need any linker to the next noun, and it means *same*. So 同じこと is *the same thing*.